# Stuck with web-service on WP7

Tags: c#, web-services, parsing, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

yesterday i did ask about how to extract some data from a complicated xml file , using web service, on the Windows Phone 7 , but unfortuntly i did not get an answer, and i'm still stuck.
This is the c# code i wrote and did not display the data on my application's screen:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;

        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=paris", UriKind.Absolute);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    }


 void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            ListBoxItem areaItem = null;
            StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            string day = String.Empty;
            string areaName = String.Empty;
            string low = String.Empty;
            string high = String.Empty;
            string condition = String.Empty;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {

                        case ("day_of_week"):
                            {
                                if (true == reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                                {
                                    reader.MoveToContent();
                                    day = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                    day = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                    areaItem.Content = day;
                                    listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);
                                }

                            } break;
                        case ("low"):
                            {
                                if (true == reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                                {
                                    reader.MoveToContent();
                                    low = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                    low = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                    areaItem.Content = low;
                                    listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);
                                }

                            } break;
                        case ("high"):
                            {
                                if (true == reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                                {
                                    reader.MoveToContent();
                                    high = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                    high = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                    areaItem.Content = high;
                                    listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);
                                }

                            } break;
                        case ("condition"):
                            {
                                if (true == reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                                {
                                    reader.MoveToContent();
                                    condition = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                    condition = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                    areaItem.Content = condition;
                                    listBox1.Items.Add(areaItem);
                                }

                            } break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }      

    }
}
```

}

Comment: please don't repost questions. See stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating everything, its really simple, use the

```
public class ForecastItem
{
 public string a {get; set;}
 public string b {get; set;}
}
```

and so on

```
private void forecastReader_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs dc)
    {
        if (dc.Error != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        XElement xmlNews = XElement.Parse(dc.Result);
        listBox1.ItemsSource = from item in xmlNews.Descendants("parent").Elements("sub")
                               select new ForecastItem
                               {
                                   a = item.Element("node").Value,
                                   b = item.Element("title").Value,                                       
                               };
    }
```

all you do from here on is Bind the Data to your XAML data template

[Article Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Hey John, i tried with your method but it didn't work neither, could you be more clear please

Comment: Actually,  with a little searching I found a solution that perfectly suits with my application's purposes.

Comment: if you found a solution please enter it here so in future people who find this may also find this solution also if you found this helpful please rate

Comment: Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: @MarTech. As you've reposted this question 3 times you could have put your answer to one of those.